# VBA: use a path in range on workbook that is not active

Tags: excel, vba, path, vlookup, lookup

I'm trying to create a tool in which I can select 2 files. In the first file a few changes are made before looking up values in the second file. I've created two paths in the tool as follows and used this code:

```
Dim File As String
Dim File2 As String
File = Sheets("Tool").Range("B2")
File2 = Sheets("Tool").Range("B3")
```

[image]

Because changes are made in "File" first, this is the active worksheet.

I want to use the following code to lookup values in the other worksheet but VBA gives me an error that it cannot find the path. I'm guessing since the tool worksheet is not the active worksheet anymore?

```
Sub vlookup()

    
    Dim rw As Long, x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(File2)
'Cannot find this file since "Tool" is not active worksheet anymore?
    
    
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Material Availability").Range("A1:H1000")

    With twb.Sheets("Material Availability")

        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.vlookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 8, False)
        Next rw

    End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where is the first bit of code in relation to the second?

Comment: Is the error you received "**Compile Error:** Invalid outside procedure" ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you bring it back to the workbook with:

```
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Activate
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(File2)
```